# How can I insert an element inside a parent element to surround another child element that is already inside the parent element?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following structure:

```
<div id="main">
<div id="1" class="1"></div>
<div id="2" class="2">
    <ul>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<div id="main">
<div id="1" class="1"></div>
<div id="2" class="2">
  <div id="3" class="3">
    <ul id="heylisten">
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is what I tried:

```
jQuery("#main .heylisten").before("<div class='caixavertficalvagas'>");
jQuery("#main .heylisten").after("</div>");
```

But this is what I'm getting:

```
<div id="main">
<div id="1" class="1"></div>
<div id="2" class="2">
<div id="3" class="3"></div>
    <ul id="heylisten">
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm already getting confused. Basically what I need is to get the `id="heylisten"` `ul` and wrap it with the div `id="3"`

Answer (score 0):

`wrap` method should work fine. You can try it like this. `heylisten` is the ID of element, not class. So you have to rewrite it as `#heylisten` while selecting.

```
jQuery("#heylisten").wrap("<div class='caixavertficalvagas'></div>");
```

Check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/melvinstanly/pa9vn5bz/

If you have multiple occurance of an element for which you need to add div as a parent, then you can use `wrapAll` method

```
 jQuery("#heylisten").wrapAll("<div class='caixavertficalvagas'></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".heylisten").wrap( "<div class='caixavertficalvagas'>" );
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer. Usually when you share an answer please add enough details on why this might work and some explanation.

Comment: Sure and Thanks @codetiger for your suggestion, i will keep in mind.